# How to read a DICOM file of Dynamic DSA image

Tags: vtk, dicom, dsa, gdcm

I have a Dynamic DSA image of DICOM format, it consists of a header of patient information etc and a series of X-ray image data to show the bone motion in only one file. Is there any method in librarys like VTK, ITK or GDCM can read this data out?

Comment: I am sorry not explain my question clearly. My question is how to read a multiple frame DICOM file that is a single file contains many 2D XA images. I know many softwares(dicom2), java library(dcm4che2) and matlab method(dicomread) can do this. But is there any method c++ libraries like VTK, ITK or GDCM can read this type of data out?

Answer (score 0):

To load a multiframe DICOM in VTK, simply use GDCM, in particular [gdcmviewer](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcmviewer.html):

```
$ gdcmviewer input.dcm
```

Comment: Thank you, you can see http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/ mutliple frames  for instance.