# How to read a multiple frames DICOM file by c++ library?

Tags: c++, vtk, dicom, gdcm

How do you read a multiple frame DICOM file that is a single file contains many 2D XA images (for example, barre.nom.fr/medical/samples). I know the software (dicom2), java library (dcm4che2) and matlab method(`dicomread`) can do this, but is there any method in c++ libraries like VTK, ITK or GDCM can read this type of data out?

Comment: Looks like the same question you asked over at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318858/how-to-read-a-dicom-file-of-dynamic-dsa-image/19402046#19402046

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use GDCM, simply check out the Examples/Cxx directory, in particurar the [HelloVizWorld](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/HelloVizWorld_8cxx-example.html) dummy example.

Comment: I don't see why this answer marked as correct when it is not even an answer

Answer (score -1):

Please use [dcmtk](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en) . Its a open source c++ library & used by many companies in industry.
Also very easy to use.