# An exception occurs when using vtkGDCMImageReader

Tags: c++, exception, gdcm

I try to use vtkGDCMImageReader to read the DICOM files, but an access violation occurred occurred when I call the update method. Here is my code:

```
vtkGDCMImageReader * reader = vtkGDCMImageReader::New();
reader->SetFileName("IMG00000");
reader->Update();
```

Is there any thing wrong with the code or simply because I didn't compile the VTK wrapper of GDCM　correctly. Can someone give me an example? Many thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the call stack for the exception?

Comment: can you prodive the dataset ?

Comment: Are you reading a series of files or just a single image file?

Comment: I want to read a single DICOM file contains multi-frames using the vtkGDCMImageReader, see another question I asked over at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428073/how-to-read-a-multiple-frames-dicom-file-by-c-library?noredirect=1#comment28839861_19428073 @drescherjm

Comment: Neither dataset can work, even a single image file or the dataset provided by gdcmData. @malat